# UseIdentityServerAuthentication for Owin API - .NET Core issue

Tags: .net, owin, .net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4

Is it possible to configure an older Owin WebAPI project to use identityserver4?

In the Owin Startup.cs file there is an *IAppBuilder* app object, however the UseIdentityServerAuthentication extension method requires an *IApplicationBuilder* app. This seems to be a difference between .NET Core and Owin.

How do I get UseIdentityServerAuthentication to work with the old IAppBuilder?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Obviously this won't work. I added this to help explain the issue.
        IApplicationBuilder app2 = (IApplicationBuilder)app;
        app2.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(
         new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
         {
             Authority = "http://localhost:8080",
             RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
             ApiName =" apiName"
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: OWIN webApi project should work without code change for both idv3 and idv4. Have you ported your webAPI project to .NET Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repo shows a couple of permutations of IdentityServer 3 and 4 used by Katana/OWIN and ASP.NET Core APIs

https://github.com/IdentityServer/CrossVersionIntegrationTests

This has everything you need.